# How to write pandas dataframe into Databricks dbfs/FileStore?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, databricks

[image][image]I'm new to the Databricks, need help in writing a pandas dataframe into databricks local file system.

I did search in google but could not find any case similar to this, also tried the help guid provided by databricks (attached) but that did not work either. Attempted the below changes to find my luck, the commands goes just fine, but the file is not getting written in the directory (expected wrtdftodbfs.txt file gets created)

1. `df.to_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/wrtdftodbfs.txt")`

Result: throws the below error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/wrtdftodbfs.txt'

2. `df.to_csv("\\dbfs\\FileStore\\NJ\\wrtdftodbfs.txt")`

Result: No errors, but nothing written either

3. `df.to_csv("dbfs\\FileStore\\NJ\\wrtdftodbfs.txt")`

Result: No errors, but nothing written either

4. `df.to_csv(path ="\\dbfs\\FileStore\\NJ\\",file="wrtdftodbfs.txt")`

> Result: TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'

5. `df.to_csv("dbfs:\\FileStore\\NJ\\wrtdftodbfs.txt")`

Result: No errors, but nothing written either

6. `df.to_csv("dbfs:\\dbfs\\FileStore\\NJ\\wrtdftodbfs.txt")`

Result: No errors, but nothing written either

The directory exists and the files created manually shows up but pandas to_csv never writes nor error out.

```
dbutils.fs.put("/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/tst.txt","Testing file creation and existence")

dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs/FileStore/NJ")
```

> Out[186]: [FileInfo(path='dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/tst.txt',
>   name='tst.txt', size=35)]

Appreciate your time and pardon me if the enclosed details are not clear enough.

Comment: Try converting it to a spark data frame then save it as a csv pandas most likely doesn't have access to the filestore

Comment: Is it a Spark dataframe or Pandas? The code at the top talks about Spark but everything else looks like Pandas. If it is involving Pandas, you need to make the file using `df.to_csv` and then use `dbutils.fs.put()` to put the file you made into the FileStore following [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html#). If it involves Spark, see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/databricks-how-to-save-files-in-csv-on-your-local-computer-3d0c70e6a9ab).

Comment: Have you tried: `with open("/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/wrtdftodbfs.txt", "w") as f: df.to_csv(f)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response Mende. I did try that but no luck, it runs fine but file is not making into the directory.

Comment: Thanks so much Wayne. The second link shared worked. I have converted pandas data frame to spark. Not sure if Databricks filestore works only thru spark commands for writing data to its file system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with this in your notebook databricks:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
CODE,L,PS
5d8A,N,P60490
5d8b,H,P80377
5d8C,O,P60491
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
#print(df)
df.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/file1.txt')

pandas_df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/FileStore/NJ/file1.txt", header='infer') 
print(pandas_df)
```

Comment: Thanks Giovani. It worked, seems the files are getting written but does not physically shows up when validated thru gui navigation or thru command fs ls.

Comment: %sh find / -type f -name "file2.txt"   recursively  @ShaanProms

Comment: Awesome! I see it. :) Thanks! The dbfs commands %fs ls /dbfs/FileStore/NJ OR dbutils.fs.ls('/dbfs/FileStore/NJ') does not show this file for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

This worked out for me:

```
outname = 'pre-processed.csv'
outdir = '/dbfs/FileStore/'
dfPandas.to_csv(outdir+outname, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

To download the file, add `files/filename` to your notebook url (before the interrogation mark `?`):

https://community.cloud.databricks.com/files/pre-processed.csv?o=189989883924552#

(you need to edit your home url, for me is :

https://community.cloud.databricks.com/?o=189989883924552#)

[dbfs file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39mVi.png)

Comment: How do you get the URL to download? can you tell any generic method to download any file

Comment: Hi Nani, if you put the path+file_name in the middle of your home URL (after .com/), it should be enough, your download should start automatically.
In my case, I had to insert "files/pre-processed.csv" in the middle of the home URL.

Comment: @MathGeek 
In databricks (Python), i use a HTML href to access the file

from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('<a href="https://community.cloud.databricks.com/files/pre-processed.csv?o=189989883924552#" >Get CSV</a>')